# Why does bash remove \n in $(cat file)?

Tags: command-line, bash

If I have the file `input.txt` containing:

```
hello
world
!
```

Then executing the bash command `echo $(cat input.txt)` will output this:

```
hello world !
```

Why and how can I fix it to output exactly what is in the file how it is in the file?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you use

```
echo "$(cat input.txt)"
```

it will work correctly.

*Probably* the input of echo is separated by newlines, and it will handle it as separate commands, so the result will be without newlines.

Comment: Nice!  So what's the difference (if any) between $( ) and backticks?  (Sorry if this is too tangential)

Comment: They are equivalent, except for the fact that $(...) is easier to nest.  In both cases, if you don't quote the result it will be tokenised into multiple arguments on white space.

Comment: But the *final* newline character is omitted, even in double quotes.  In contrast, Perl's backtick operator expands to the entire output of the command, including all newlines.

Comment: @KeithThompson yes, command substitution removes all trailing newlines from the output. That has the advantage of e.g. `echo "$(date) something"` stripping away the trailing newline from date's output, making that echo output the date and "something" on the same line. If you need to store a file or command output "as is", use mapfile (`help mapfile`), `read -rd ''` or a while read-loop.

Comment: Thanks everyone :-)  I learned something from every comment here!

Answer (score 9):

Quoted from bash manual page, section `Command Substitution`:

> Embedded newlines are not deleted, but  they  may be removed during
>   word splitting.

A little further, same section :

> If the substitution appears within double quotes, word splitting and
>   pathname expansion are not performed  on
>          the results.

That's why `echo "$(cat /etc/passwd)"`  works.

Additionally, one should be aware, that command substitution [by POSIX specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03) removes trailing newlines:

```
$ echo "$(printf "one\ntwo\n\n\n")"
one
two
```

Thus, outputting a file via `$(cat file.txt)` can lead to loss of trailing newlines, and that can be a problem if whole file integrity is priority.

Answer (score 7):

You can preserve newlines, for example by setting IFS to empty:

```
$ IFS=
$ a=$(cat links.txt)
$ echo "$a"
link1
link2
link3
```