# How can I print multiline output on the same line?

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing

Is there a method to print multi-line output (single output) on the same line?

For example, if the output is:

```
abc
def
qwerty
```

Is it possible to print:

```
abcdefqwerty
```

Answer (score 16):

You can remove all occurrences of characters from a given set with `tr -d`. To remove the newline character use:

```sh
tr -d '\n'
```

As always you can use input and output redirection and pipes to read from or write to files and other processes.

If you want to keep the last newline you can simply add it back with `echo` or `printf '\n'`, e. g.:

```sh
cat file1 file2... | { tr -d '\n'; echo; } > output.txt
```

Comment: For those that want to keep a space between each line, you can use `tr '\n' ' '`

Answer (score 11):

Many ways. To illustrate, I have saved your example in `file`:

```
$ cat file | tr -d '\n'
abcdefqwerty$ 
$ cat file | perl -pe 's/\n//'
abcdefqwerty$
```

That removes all newline characters, including the last one though. You might instead want to do:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "$(cat file | perl -pe 's/\n//')"
abcdefqwerty
$ printf "%s\n" "$(cat file | tr -d '\n')"
abcdefqwerty
```

Comment: I think the `printf` + `cat` + `perl` combo is much better handled via `perl -pe 's/\n//;END{printf "\n"}' input.txt`  Single process, no command-substitution and messing with quotes, and no UUOC. Perhaps.

Answer (score 7):

You can pipe your multiline output through `awk`

```bsh
awk '{printf "%s",$0} END {print ""}'
```

or use `sed`:

```bsh
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'
```

#### Example run

```bsh
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4" | awk '{printf "%s",$0} END {print ""}'
1234
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'              
1234
```

Further reading: [remove line break using AWK · serverfault.SE](https://serverfault.com/questions/391360/remove-line-break-using-awk)

Answer (score 4):

Also `your_command | paste -sd ''` which preserves the trailing newline.

Answer (score 4):

This answer has a solution to the problem you are trying to create: [Why does bash remove \n in $(cat file)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121866/why-does-bash-remove-n-in-cat-file)

If you type `cat myfile.txt` you will see:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

But if you type `echo $(cat myfile.txt)` you will see:

```
abc def ghi
```

Note this method inserts a space where separate new lines used to be. This makes the output easier to read but doesn't strictly adhere to your question scope.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Perl for this, you can use its `chomp` function:

```bash
perl -pe chomp
```

---

#### Some more details, for those who are interested.

You can pass one or more filenames as subsequent arguments.

```bash
perl -pe chomp file1 file2 file3
```

[In some cases you might not want to do that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170013/security-implications-of-running-perl-ne), but you can pipe or redirect to that command instead. (These abilities--and that caveat--all apply to any other `perl -p` or `perl -n` based solution, too.)

So, if you want to process output from running *`some-command`*:

```bash
some-command | perl -pe chomp
```

This is potentially faster than the Perl command in [terdon's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/988651/22949). Newline characters (represented by `\n`) only appear at the end of lines in this situation--because they are what Perl is using to decide where each line ends. `s/\n//` searches through the entire line for newlines, while `chomp` just removes the one at the end (if any, as the very last line might or might not have one).

Performance might not really be the main reason to prefer `chomp`. The  `perl` command in [terdon's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/988651/22949) would only be slightly slower unless you're processing a huge file with very long lines. And if you need speed, [David Foerster's way](https://askubuntu.com/a/988650/22949) is still probably faster. `chomp` is, however, exactly the right tool for this if you are using Perl, and I think the intent of `chomp` is clearer than that of `s/\n//`. Ultimately there's probably no objective answer as to which is better.

#### Printing a final newline.

However, I do recommend against the use of command substitution (`$(` `)`) just to ensure a trailing newline gets printed. Unless the text you're processing is short, that's likely to be quite slow--it has to collect all the text at once and then print it--and it makes your command harder to understand. Instead you can do [as David Foerster suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/988650/22949) and run `echo` or `printf '\n'` afterwards.

```bash
perl -pe chomp; echo
```

If you're piping *from* or (as David Foerster shows) redirecting *from* that command, then you can enclose it in `{` `;}` so that the output of both commands is taken together. If you're just printing it to the terminal, then you can run it exactly as shown above. This works even if you're piping or redirecting *to* the command, because `echo`/`printf '\n'` does not actually read any input. That is, this works:

```bash
some-command | perl -pe chomp; echo
```

While here you cannot simply remove the `{` `;}`:

```bash
{ perl -pe chomp; echo; } | some-other-command
```

Or, if you prefer, you can make `perl` print the final newline itself. Like enclosing the `perl` and `echo` commands in `{` `;}`, this approach works even if you're piping or redirecting *from* it (and, like *all* approaches, this works when you're piping *to* it, too):

```bash
perl -wpe 'chomp; END { print "\n" }'
```

Note that the command in terdon's answer works fine with these methods of printing the final newline, too. For example:

```bash
perl -pe 's/\n//'; echo
```

```bash
perl -pe 's/\n//; END { print "\n" }'
```

Comment: `perl -wpe 'chomp; END { print "\n" }`  is same process, minor advantage over adding trailing echo

Answer (score 1):

Using shell-only way:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do printf "%s"  "$line"; done < inputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bash, then you can do it without any external tool.

```
x=($(echo line1; echo line2))
echo "${x[@]}"
```

Result:

```
line1 line2
```

The first command turn multiline output into an array, the second command expand array into multiple arguments on one line.