# Variable with quotation marks "$()"

Tags: bash, scripts

I wrote this script :

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ] 
do
    currentoutput="$(lsusb)"
    if [ "$currentoutput" != "$lastoutput" ]
    then
        echo "" date and Time >> test.log
        date +%x_r >> test.log
        lastoutput="$(lsusb)"
        lsusb >> test.log
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

I'm a newbie trying to learn fast and I got a question about the variable’s **quotation marks**.

Put a variable between $(), I get it, but why are the **quotation marks** needed even in the `if` statement? Is it to make a nested command?

Comment: Note that `while [ true ]` does produce an infinite loop, but perhaps not for the reason you think it does; `while [ false ]` *also* produces an infinite loop, because with a single argument, `[ ... ]` succeeds if that argument is a non-empty string. `while true` will actually *run* a command named `true` (which always succeeds).

Comment: You don't put a variable inside `$()`.  You put a **command** inside `$()`.

Comment: Try this: `$ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" $(lsusb)` versus the same thing, but with double quotes `$ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" "$(lsusb)"`. For extra xp, also try the following: `"\`lsusb\`"`  `\`lsusb\``  `'$(lsusb)'` Quiz: what will `\`$(lsusb)\`` do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Quotation marks prevent "word splitting". That is: breaking down variables into multiple items at whitespace characters (or to be more exact, at spaces, tabs, and newlines as defined in the value of the default `$IFS` shell variable).

For example,

```
$ var="one two"
$ howmany(){ echo $#;  }
$ howmany $var
2
$ howmany "$var"
1
```

Here we define the `howmany` function which just lets us know how many positional parameters are given. As you can see, there are two items being passed to the variable, and with the quotes the text in the variable is treated as one unit.

This is important for accurate passing of information. For example, if the variable contains path to file, and the filename contains spaces anywhere in the path, the command you are trying to run may fail or give inaccurate results. If we were trying to create a file with the `$var` variable, `touch $var` would create two files, but `touch "$var"` just one.

Same goes for your `[ "$currentoutput" != "$lastoutput" ]` part. This particular test performs a comparison on two strings. When the test runs, the `[` command would need to see 3 arguments - a text string, the `!=` operator, and another text string. Keeping double quotes prevents word splitting, and the `[` command sees exactly those 3 arguments. Now what happens if variables are unquoted ?

```
$ var="hello world"
$ foo="hi world"
$ [ $var != $foo ]
bash: [: too many arguments
$
```

Here, word splitting occurs, and instead `[` sees two strings `hello` and `world` followed by `!=`, followed by two other strings `hi world`. Key point is that without double quotes, the contents of variables are understood as separate units rather than one whole item.

Assigning command substitution doesn't require double quotes as in

```
var=$( df )
```

where you have the `df` command's output saved to `var`. However, it is a good habit to always double quote variables and command substitution `$(...)` unless you do in fact want the output to be treated as separate items.

---

On a side note, the

```
while [ true ]
```

part can be

```
while true
```

`[` is a command which evaluates its arguments, and `[ whatever ]` is always true regardless of what is inside. By contrast, `while true` uses the command `true` which always returns success exit status (and that's exactly what `while` loop needs). The difference is a bit more clarity and less testing performed. Alternatively, you could also use `:` instead of `true`

The double quotes in `echo "" date and Time` part could probably be removed. They merely insert an empty string and an add extra space to the output. If that's desired, feel free to keep them there, but there's no particular functional value in this case.

```
lsusb >> test.log
```

This part could probably be replaced with `echo "$currentoutput" >> test.log`. There's no reason to run `lsusb` again after it has been run already in `currentoutput=$(lsusb)`.  In cases where [trailing newlines](https://askubuntu.com/a/754514/295286) 
 have to be preserved in the output - one could see the value in running a command multiple times, but in case of `lsusb` there's no need for that. The less external commands you call, the better, because every call to a non-built-in command incurs costs in CPU, memory usage, and execution time ( even though the commands are probably pre-loaded from memory).

---

See also:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)
- [What is the point of the bash null operator : (colon)?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1042780/295286)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/)

Comment: Great answer, if you didn't already, you should write a book about `bash`. But in the last part shouldn't `echo "$currentoutput" >> test.log` [better be](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) `printf '%s\n' "$currentoutput" >> test.log` ?

Comment: @RoVo Yes, `printf` should be preferred for portability. Since we're using bash-specific script here it can be excused to use `echo`. But your observation is very much correct

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, ...I'm not sure that `echo` is completely reliable even when the shell is known to be bash (and the value of the `xpg_echo` and `posix` flags is known); if your value could be `-n` or `-e`, it can disappear instead of being printed.

Answer (score 4):

The following runs the external command `command` and returns its output.

```
"$(command)"
```

Without the brackets/parentheses, this would look for a variable instead of running a command:

```
"$variable"
```

As for the difference between `$variable` and `"$variable"`, this becomes relevant when `$variable` contains spaces.  When using `"$variable"`, the entire variable contents will be inserted into a single string even if the contents include spaces.  When using `$variable` the contents of the variable may be expanded into an argument list of multiple arguments.

Comment: HI @thomasrutter,

I'm sorry, i meant quotation mark ...

I edit my comment now !

Answer (score 4):

In `currentoutput="$(lsusb)"` lsusb is not a variable, it is a command. What this statement does, it executes `lsusb` command and assigns its output to `currentoutput` variable.

Older syntax for this was

```
currentoutput=`lsusb`
```

you can find it in many examples and scripts

To answer the other part of your question, `if [ ]` is just how syntax for `if` is defined in bash. See more in https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Comment: I think it's important to say that `[ ]` is actually the `test` command. You can use `if` statements with other commands too, as it relies on a 0 or non-zero test of their exit code.

Comment: ...indeed, it's much better to run `if grep -qe "somestring" file` than to run `grep -qe "somestring" file; if [ $? = 0 ]; then ...`, so the claim that `if [ ...` is part of the definition of `if` syntax is not just misleading but leads to bad practices.

Answer (score 2):

To be contrarian - bash recommends you use the `[[ ... ]]` over the `[ ... ]` construct to avoid having to quote variables in the test and so the associated problems of word splitting that the others have pointed out.

`[` is provided in bash for POSIX compatibility with scripts meant to run under `#!/bin/sh` or those being ported over to bash - for the most part, you should avoid it in favour of `[[`.

e.g.

```bsh
# With [ - quotes are needed

$ foo='one two'; bar='one two'; [ $foo = $bar ] && echo "they're equal"
-bash: [: too many arguments

$ foo='one two'; bar='one two'; [ "$foo" = "$bar" ] && echo "they're equal"                                                                                                              
they're equal

# versus [[ - quotes not needed

$ foo='one two'; bar='one two'; [[ $foo = $bar ]] && echo "they're equal"
they're equal
```

Comment: `bash` makes no such recommendation; it *provides* `[[ ... ]]` which can be more convenient and has some functionality that `[ ... ]` does not, but there is no problem with using `[ ... ]` *correctly*.

Comment: @chepner - Maybe I should be clearer here. Sure it's not an explicit recommendation in the bash manpage but given `[[` does everything `[` does and more and still the many times `[` trips people up and then try and retrofit features of `[[` back to `[` only to fail and leave bugs scattered about - it's fair to say it is a _community recommendation_ in as far as most relevant bash style guides will advise _never use `[`_.